# How to shorten alpine slings into an alpine quickdraw?

Tags: climbing

Alpine slings are usually 60cm long and while they can be slung over one shoulder, it's much easier to carry them on your harness at 1/3 of the size in an alpine quickdraw.

How would one shorten them up into an alpine quickdraw?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simple way is to pass one of the carabiners through the other,

[image]

then clip that carabiner to the slings on the other side.

[image]

Finally, you pull both carabiners tight to dress the whole thing.

[image]

To undo , you unclip any two of the strands from one carabiner and pull. This can be useful because you can reach up, clip in with one carabiner, undo two strands from the second and then pull and the sling will be ready to go.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make them even more compact (especially for longer slings), you can hold onto the biners, and twist one a couple of times, then continue twisting in the same direction and clip one biner onto the other.  Be careful not to put so much twist on them that it imprints.  (For storage, it's probably best to untwist and store them flat.)  Also, I find the dyneema material's thinness helps to keep the sling manageable.

Pictured is actually a [Mammut 120cm sling](https://www.rei.com/product/830934/mammut-contact-sling-dyneema-80) (full strength - 22kN) with [Black Diamond Neutrino](https://www.rei.com/product/113465/black-diamond-neutrino-wiregate-carabiner) wiregates (24kN on axis and closed, 7kN off or open)

[image: 120cm dyneema sling as quickdraw, twisted for compactness]